# Video game main menu tab navigation mapping for PC

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, games

The tab navigation menu is very common for console video games. It is usually mapped on LB/RB buttons (Xbox).
[image: Tab navigation in Fortnite]

I wonder what would be the most intuitive mapping for PC keyboard?

In Windows, this behaviour is mapped on **Ctrl+Tab** (forward) and **Ctrl+Shift+Tab** (backwards), but for the game that's too many keys. I am looking for a single key alternative.

Comment: I hope I understand the question correctly, but why not use key arrows , left and right?

Comment: Arrow keys are used for Directional navigation. When you have something focused, say a button in a list of buttons, you can move the focus to the next item with the arrow key. I am looking for hotkeys that would not depend from the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Q and E. These are keys most PC gamers will easily associate with "left" and "right" since they are used for equipment as well as leaning in some first- and third-person games. E might be a tough choice if it is leveraged elsewhere in the game, especially if it's used within the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the top row numbers, since both the interface buttons and keyboard buttons are top rows.

Same reason they are mapped to LB RB in the Xbox controller.

---

**Update:**
Maybe PageUp, PageDown. 
Regardless of the mapping, consider providing an option for the user to set themselves. Gamers are very peculiar with mapping of key and functions.

Comment: These should correspond to navigate forward and backwards through tabs, not the hotkeys for each tab.

Comment: updated comment